# Need to create WSO2 DSS service which can read parameter from url

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have created a simple dss service which by inputing cust_id it gives me the customer data.

I have exposed this webservice as http get resource with the following url
GET /services/getCustDetailDSS/getDetail?cid=101

Corrsponding  xml code for my service is as follows

```
<data name="getCustomerDetailDSS" serviceGroup="" serviceNamespace="">
<description/>
<config id="mydb">
    <property name="carbon_datasource_name">mydb</property>
</config>
<query id="get_customer_detail" useConfig="mydb">
    <sql>select identifier,user_status from customer_detail where identifier = :cid</sql>
    <param name="cid" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <result element="customer">
        <element column="identifier" name="cid" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="user_status" name="status" xsdType="xs:string"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="get_customer_detail_operation">
    <call-query href="get_customer_detail">
        <with-param name="cid" query-param="identifier"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<resource method="GET" path="/getDetail">
    <call-query href="get_customer_detail">
        <with-param name="cid" query-param="cid"/>
    </call-query>
</resource>
</data>
```

But now i want the dss service to read cust_id from url instead of passing it as a parameter.

i.e i want to hit dss service as 
GET /services/getCustDetailDSS/cid/101/getDetail

How can i do this in DSS ?

Can anyone provide wat changes i need to do in my dss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `GET /services/getCustDetailDSS/getDetail/cid/101`

You have to edit your resource path as follows.

```
<resource method="GET" path="getDetail/cid/{cid}">
```

Comment: this is not working...bcoz if i add this path n after if there is parameter url is like /getDetail/cid/?identifier=? and if i dont add query param (which is i want to do) url is like /getDetail/cid/. and if i enter id after /cid/ and try to hit it from soapui i get the error DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR\nNested Exception:-\njavax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'Query.extractParams', cannot find query param with name:cid\nDS

Comment: That should be working. What is the DSS version you are using? Try this curl command too. (modify ip/port accordingly)
`curl -k -H "Accept: application/json" https://10.213.209.1:9483/services/getCustDetailDSS.HTTPEndpoint/getDetail/cid/101`

Comment: i m using dss 3.2.0. I tried the above curl command but getting the same error as described in my first comment.Also i m adding additional response stmts in this comments.. \nDefault Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice\nCurrent Request Name: _get_getstatus_cid\nCurrent Params: {}\n\n","Detail":""}}

Comment: Can u put the xml code of data service if u have tried in your system?

Comment: I tried in DSS 3.1.1 only. I will try on 3.2.0 one too. There is a sample DSS service (samples/ResourcesSample) which comes with DSS pack. That is the sample for what you are looking for. Try if it works for you.

Comment: I tried in 3.2.1 and it works fine when `Accept: application/xml`. But I get a different exception when `Accept: application/json`. I will send and email to dev list and reply back once I get a response. Meanwhile you can try with `Accept: application/xml`

Comment: i'm still getting incompatible parameters error with xml accept header..looks like i'm making some mistake while creating dss service.i m posting the xml of my resource part of service in next comment...can u check and tell me whether it is correct or not...

Comment: <resource method="GET" path="/getDetail/{cid}">
        <call-query href="get_customer_detail"/>
    </resource>

Comment: You need `<with-param name="cid" query-param="cid"/>` part too. Try removing starting slash in path too. `path="getDetail/{cid}"`

Comment: yah it worked...thanks alot bhathiya for all your help...previuosly wen i added parameter with resource it was not working..i guess i myt have made some mistake...now after adding paramters with resource it is wroking perfectly fine..thanks a lot

Comment: Also Accept:application/json is also working in mine.

Comment: Good to hear that... :)

Comment: i am looking for this, but what if i have 2 params or more with nullable value?

Answer (score 0):

With WSO2 DSS 3.2.1, you can now define your query string parameter as below:

```
<param name="cid" sqlType="QUERY_STRING"/>
```

instead of:

```
<param name="cid" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING"/>
```

and your URL should look like:

```
.../getDetail?cid=101
```